# Ground voltage trips separate GFCIs

Tags: electrical-panel, circuit-breaker

New construction, new panel, when welder is switched on voltage is seen on the ground leg (both 240 & 120v plugs). This causes other GFCIs connected to the panel to trip. They are on separate breakers. Upon checking the ground wire we saw 11v (up to 60 on startup). We’ve removed ground from the welder and all works correctly (no trips). Any ideas? It doesn’t trip panel breakers.

Comment: Have you checked how the ground from the welder is internally connected?

Comment: Sounds like you need to repair the welder, or correct an improperly wired welder plug/receptacle (new construction should mean no NEMA 10s, but we've seen people illegally and improperly install them...)

Comment: Where is your welder return ("ground") clamp connected? What are you measuring the voltage relative to? Is it DC or AC?

Comment: The welder return is not connected to anything as of yet… (just purchased…) We were checking basic functionality. This is a multi purpose welder (Yeswelder CT2050). Voltage is being measured at plug socket from ground pin to copper wire going to panel… No welding taking place yet, as it trips the lighting circuit GFCI along with another.

Comment: New service and panel installed by licensed electrician, checked by a second and passed inspection.

Comment: Manufacturer made aware of issue, asked for and got internal pictures. Looking for other possibilities before returning. I appreciate all ideas. BTW, dryer and other appliances have not caused any issues.